# Can I restrict the webservices available to a glassfish virtual server

Tags: glassfish

I have an ear with quite a few web services. I'm now at a point where I need to expose a couple of them to a 3rd party. To manage the connectivity I was going to create a virtual server however it seems I have to make the entire ear available.

What I'd like to do is create virtual server and say it only has access to these few / specific web services.

Using Glassfish 3.12

Answer (score 0):

You must implement an authentication & authorization mechanism in your web services, so only allowed parties can access them.